# What is "Used" role in this sentence?

Tags: verbs

What is "Used" role in this sentence?
The polymers ***used*** have for the most part been derived from ... .

Comment: If you supplant in what feels missing, it might make more sense. -> "The polymers (*that were*) used have for the most part been derived from... "

Comment: It's a past participle functioning as head of the past participial clause modifying "polymers". Semantically, it is the equivalent of the relative clause, cf. "The polymers that are used have for the most part been derived from ... ."

Comment: So it is a correct form to write, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's okay.

Comment: or read it as "the polymers used (in the construction) have for..."